# to find in which directions does Derivatives at a point exists?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If suppose I have a fuction e.g. $f(x,y,z)=|x+y+z|$ ,and I'm asked to prove that in which directions does derivative of $f$ at a point,(say $e_1-e_2$) it exists.

How to think about the problem ?

Comment: Do you mean at what points $(x,y,z)$ does the derivative exists. Or are you asking about Gateaux derivatives?

Comment: @copper.hat I'm asking given a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ in which directions does the derivative exist...

Comment: You need to elaborate. Unless you are talking about a specific type of derivative, if the derivative exists, there is no direction as such. It can be evaluated in a particular direction, but if it exists, it can be evaluated in any direction you want.

Comment: @copper.hat when I mean to ask this I'm asking :given a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ which directional derivatives exist...Does this makes some sense now...

Comment: Yes. That was what my first comment was asking.

Comment: First, the derivative exists at all points except along one specific line, hence for all points except on this  line, the directional derivative exists. For points on the line, it depends on whether you are asking for the one sided directional derivative or the two sided directional derivative (European or African swallow?).

Comment: Sorry, I mean a line.

Comment: One- or two-sided directional derivatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider $\phi(x) = |x|$. $\phi$ is differentiable except for $x = 0$ and for $x \neq 0$, the derivative is given by $\phi'(x) = \operatorname{sgn x}$.

The function $\phi$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, but does have one sided
directional derivatives at $x=0$. It is easy to compute $d\phi (x,h) = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} {\phi(x+th) - \phi(x) \over t}$ as $d \phi (0,h) = |h|$.

If we let $Lx = x_1+x_2+x_3$, then we see that $f = \phi \circ L$ is differentiable as long as $Lx \neq 0$, and the derivative is given by the chain rule.

Finally, we have $df(x,h) = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} {f(x+th) - f(x) \over t} = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} {\phi(Lx+tLh) - \phi(Lx) \over t} = d \phi(Lx,Lh)$.

Hence if $Lx = 0$, we have $df(x,h) = |Lh|$.